# Collecting vinyl LPs on an open shelf

Tags: storage, music

I have a moderate but rapidly-growing collection of vinyl LPs. I want to keep these LPs on an open shelf, without them spilling over. Unfortunately, record storage crates won't fit on the shelf (at least not without hiding the records from view and making access cumbersome), and even the heaviest bookends I've found won't prevent the records from toppling over and shoving them over due to their sheer weight.  What are some ways I can go about storing my records in an accessible, attractive way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your records in a rigid (plastic or metal) open-front magazine holder, such as one of these:

[image: Magazine holder]
[image: Magazine holder]

The magazine holders themselves all but disappear when they're placed side-by-side, as seen in this setup:

[image: Magazine holders in action]

Image sources: [Amazon listing for Acrimet Magazine File Holder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00INAD4ZW), [Rubbermaid 96502ROS Deluxe Magazine Rack](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IANT)

Comment: Please be aware that we don't want product recommendation as a general rule here on Lifehacks SE. The better approach is to desrcribe the product in general terms, and possibly include an image with a reference to where it comes from.

Comment: @holroy Duly noted!

Answer (score 1):

One way which was used back in the days, was drilling small holes in the shelf, and then using bent metal rods as shelf dividers. This could be moved at your pleasure. A variant over these theme could be to general [shelf dividers (google image search)](https://www.google.no/search?tbm=isch&q=shelf+dividers).

As shown in images in above linke various alternatives exists, with various support strength, but in general these can be made sturdy enough to support LP's, and still be almost invisible, and thereby really showcasing the albums.

Answer (score 1):

Milk crates make excellent record holders, and the fact that they can stack means that your shelving dimensions are quite flexible.

[image: vianls]

Comment: Please don't link images from other sites like this, it's better that you upload them using the add picture when editing the post. And it could very well be sized down a little.

Comment: @holroy, I thought that SE would make a copy of the linked picture.  I can't scale it down much further than I just did, and a better image isn't making itself apparent to me.  Thanks though.

Comment: Any chance you can source where you retrieved the image from?

Comment: @Kevin Brown, like an official "avoid copyright infringement" way?  Otherwise, it's one of the top google image hits for "milk crate records".

Comment: Milk crates are the gold standard but I couldn't find any that would have fit in my existing shelves. :) For making new shelving they're great though.

Answer (score -1):

lay a stack on each end flat  i think a stack of 20 or so should be ok and not damage the records due to presure

Comment: This answer is pretty unclear. Care to elaborate and maybe provide a diagram?

Comment: This works with books but an LP left lying flat will warp. Store all your vinyl disks vertically.